# Java Print Array With External Method

Tags: java, arrays, class, for-loop, methods

I'm making a program to display the names, ages and gpa's of a class which has been stored in an array. I made the Student class with a constructor, accessors and a method to print out the details.

In the main method, I populate the array and want to display all of the items in the array (this is what I'm having trouble with).

This is what I have so far:

```
public class Student {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private double gpa;

public Student(String studentName, int studentAge, double studentGpa) {
   this.name = studentName;
   this.age = studentAge;
   this.gpa = studentGpa;
}

//Normal accessors, not going to bother putting them on here.

public void printStudents() {
   System.out.println("Name: " + name + ", Age: " + age + ", GPA: " + gpa);
}

//New class, imagine it's on a different file

public class MyClass {

private static Student [] students = new Student[3];

System.out.println("Students in my class");

students[0] = new Student("Mark",16,77.6);
students[1] = new Student("Sam",17,56.9);
students[2] = new Student("Polly",16,97.4);

for (int g = 0; g < students.length; g++) {
//This is where I'm stuck, I'm not sure how to call printStudents here. students.printStudents didn't work for some reason.
```

Comment: its an array, so use `students[g].printStudents()`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I love your username btw. :D

Comment: Note: `printStudents()` should not have a plural name if it is in the `Student` class: it prints the details of just one student.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private double gpa;

public Student(String studentName, int studentAge, double studentGpa) {
   this.name = studentName;
   this.age = studentAge;
   this.gpa = studentGpa;
}
public void printStudent() {
   System.out.println("Name : "+this.name);
   System.out.println("Age : "+this.age);
   System.out.println("GPA : "+this.gpa);
}
 }




public class MyClass {
public static void main(String s[])
{

 Student [] students = new Student[3];

System.out.println("Students in my class");

students[0] = new Student("Mark",16,77.6);
students[1] = new Student("Sam",17,56.9);
students[2] = new Student("Polly",16,97.4);

for (int i = 0; i <=(students.length-1); i++) {
    students[i].printStudent();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Hello_World mentioned in the comments - change `printStudents` method name to `printStudent` to make more sense. It is a public method of the `Student` object, which means you access it directly from the instance of the object (for example `students[0].printStudent()`). Also you can iterate through an Array with a foreach cycle, which is a bit easier to read.

```
students[0] = new Student("Mark", 16, 77.6);
students[1] = new Student("Sam", 17, 56.9);
students[2] = new Student("Polly", 16, 97.4);

for (Student student : students) {
    student.printStudent();
}
```